# Resize Uibutton with Auto Layout & size class

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have developing app for iPhone & iPad. so I choose Auto Layout & Size class its bit complex to understand. I have tried to add number pad with my app Please refer the screenshots.I added iPhone 6, iPhone 4s and iPad screenshot. I want exactly iPhone 6(screen1) output. but I cant get it in iphone 4s(screen2).

in iPad(screen3) atleast need to show those buttons at center of the screen. can any one help on this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I try to set less or greater then size to buttons but its not working. please suggest me how to make same look on all screens.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the same results for different iPhones and iPads you must actually work with and implement the size classes you chose. Please refer to Apple's manual at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

Another great tutorial is at: http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/

As you mentioned in your question- size classes might be less intuitive. From my experience, reading Apple's manual will help you understand how to accomplish exactly what you need.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer. Brilliant reply!!